# Oracle store procedure will return all the data from table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

This is function will return the all the row from the table I am sending as a parameter

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_results(tables_name IN varchar2)
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  IS
  l_rc SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN l_rc
    FOR 'SELECT *
     FROM ' || tables_names ;
  RETURN l_rc;
END;
```

This procedure will call the above function. I will just call the procedure with category name and want to get all the values from those tables which are associated with the category.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE select_record(category_name IN VARCHAR2) 
  AS 
  type tableaarray IS VARRAY(20) OF VARCHAR2(20); 
  tables_names tableaarray; 
  total integer;
  result SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN 
  IF category_name = 'jobs' THEN
    tables_names := tableaarray('categories');   
  ELSIF category_name = 'alert' THEN
    tables_names := tableaarray('alert_demo');   
  END IF;  
  total := tables_names.count;

  FOR i in 1 .. total LOOP 
    result := get_results(tables_names(i));

  END LOOP; 
END;
```

Now the problem is in the loop. I can't display the output which I am getting in the loop. The approach might not right. I am new to plsql. Please give me some idea how can I do this.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of this [LINK](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34180/how-and-when-to-use-sys-refcursor-in-oracle) ?

Comment: What do you like to do with the result? Just printing on screen?

Answer (score 0):

This really seems like an antipattern to me. You're doing `SELECT *` in your cursor, so you're getting back a different list of columns for each table name.

Why are you doing it this way rather than actually selecting the columns you need from the tables you're interested in?

If you really have to do this, I'd suggest doing dynamic SQL with the [DBMS_SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS058) package. That's a fairly complex thing and you say you're new to PL/SQL so, I dunno...